# Retornar a ultima data do Array

Tags: javascript, data, react

Olá, eu tenho um código onde estou buscando uma lista de datas.

```
    for(var i = 0; i < data.list.length; i++){
      if(Date.parse(data.list[i].date) >= dateA){

            console.log(data.list[i].date)


      }          
  }
```

eu gostaria saber se existe possibilidade de retornar apenas a ultima data do array.

Comment: Pra qualquer array, o último elemento pode ser acessado usando `minhaArray[minhaArray.length - 1]`

Answer (score 0):

Só pegar o tamanho do array, seu tamanho é o index do seu ultimo valor

```
var t = data.list.length;

console.log(data.list[t].date);
```

Acho que isso resolve

Mas caso você queira pegar a ultima data e não o ultimo index, vc pode fazer um sort no array e então pegar o ultimo index

```
array.sort();
```

Comment: Não da certo kkk, deixa eu explicar de uma forma melhor, eu tenho um data no meu banco de dados dia 28/03 e outra 31/03, eu quero pegar a data mais próxima do dia de hoje, ou seja 28/03, no meu caso seria a ultima listada no array

Comment: então eu usaria data.list.sort(); ?

Comment: O sort faz ordenar do menor para o maior, teste com o sort e me fala se funcionou

Comment: é que na verdade eu não quer ordenar, eu so quero listar a data mais próxima do dia de hoje e ignorar as outras maiores

Comment: Sim, se você ordena-las, o ultimo index conterá a ultima data, a mais próxima no caso, vc disse que os dados vem de um db, qual db seria? Pq já não traz na query a ultima data?